# Scroll issue on the page I developed

Tags: css

I'm currently working on the page of a site.

In this page the top bar is stuck at the top when i scroll down.
This issue occurs only in the Chrome browser.
When i opened it in Safari or other browsers it is working perfectly fine.

I tried disabling Javascript thinking js would have caused the problem. But the errror still occured.
I think the issue is with css style. but i'm not sure.

What would be causing this problem ?
Help me to sovle this issue.

If you need anything i can add here...

I expect to solve this problem in chrome since many people are using chrome.

Comment: Check your console and fix the shown errors.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Jquery has been initialized in both top and bottom of the page.
Use only one jquery and that is at the bottom side of the code.
From console, error looks like some order mismatch in initializing.
Please change the order of js import (First jquery-3.3.1.min.js then bootstrap.min.js and all other js files)[image: source code]

Answer (score 0):

I checked your page out buddy, I don't see any top bars. Can you clarify further?[your page as seen by me in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQjqQ.png)

If you meant the logo and the white line on the top, they are not fixed and scroll fine with the rest of the page.